# Why is chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener not firing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to listen to updates to a tab's URL in a chrome extension. The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onUpdated) for chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener explains that updates to attributes like url will trigger the listener, but I am only seeing updates for the loading status or an empty changeInfo object.

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab)=>{
    console.log("change info", changeInfo);
});
```

What I see in the console when I navigate to new URLs, either via the search bar or clicking on links:

```
change info {status: 'loading'}
change info {}
change info {}
change info {status: 'complete'}
```

How could a listener be triggered on an empty changeInfo object? and why do none of the updates include url changes? What am I doing wrong here? (this is not limited to chrome, reproduced in safari as well).

Comment: You also need `tabs` permission to see the `url` as noted in the documentation.

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm . I found using a host permission also works if you're looking to detect changes only on a certain site.